# Needs unrotten DRINK_MAT-producing plants

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a large amount of `plump helmets` to make alcohol. Some have been placed in barrels, and others placed directly on the food stockpile.

The `Still` is in the same room as the food stockpile where all the plants are. Whenever I get new plants, I always begin making alcohol with the Still by queuing up the brew from plant option.

The brewer begins brewing, but after a minute or two, I suddenly get spammed with messages that say:

`<dwarf_name> cancels Brew drink from plant: Needs unrotten DRINK_MAT-producing plants`

Then the option to brew from plant becomes red. Yet, my food stockpile still has a large amount of plump helmets.

There is a [thread on bay12forums](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=140145.0) that has the same problem, and the proposed checklist on page 2 does not apply to me because:

(a) My stockpile is not linked to my Still. Anyone can access it.

(b) My plants are not being hauled. They are already on the ground in the stockpile or in standing barrels.

(c) My stockpile and Still are not in a burrow.

I'm using Mayday tileset, although I don't think this should matter?

What could be wrong?

Comment: For this kind of question it might help to post a save file, and a link to said save file. The only two things I can think of off the top of my head are that the stockpile might be linked to something, or you have turned off brewing plump helmets in the kitchen status screen. But there are probably other potential reasons that I am not thinking of.

Comment: Are plump helmets permitted to be brewed on the kitchen stocks screen?

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this now. I didn't realize that white text meant that the condition was satisfied:

[image]

I was missing an "Empty food storage item". Building a wooden barrel at the carpenter shop resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem as you are seeing. [From what I understand](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=8491), graphic tilesets actually modify the object raw files (in this instance, either the one for plump helmets or the brew drinks reaction), so if you install a tileset not built for a specific version of DF it will sometimes break things in the game. I ended up solving my problem with a fresh install of DF. If you really want to save a current game, reinstalling the specific version of the graphics tileset for your version of DF might fix it.